# C# BsonDocument remove element

Tags: c#, bson

I hava a BsonDocument

```
var document =  { "$match" : 
    { 
        "resume.Id" : ObjectId("5450e7c7d7c1820e40020d10"), 
        "accountSettings.HideInfo" : false, 
        "Nationality" : { "$in" : [] }, 
        "ComName" : { "$in" : [] }, 
        "resume.code" : { "$in" : [] } 
    }
}
```

Is there any way to remove eleement

```
"ComName" : { "$in" : [] }
```

or

```
"resume.code" : { "$in" : [] }
```

I trying to use

```
document.Values.ToBsonDocument().Remove("ComName");
```

but is doesn't work

Comment: Are you even keeping the result? Because the line above just throws it away again

Comment: I found the answer document.GetElement("$match").Value.ToBsonDocument().Remove("ComName") Thank :D

Answer (score 1):

So, the solution for this question is:

```
document.GetElement("$match").Value.ToBsonDocument().Remove(‌​"ComName")
```

Here is the explanation:

1.Take the element by name:

```
document.GetElement("$match")
```

2.Take element's value:

```
document.GetElement("$match").Value
```

3.Convert to BsonDocument

```
document.GetElement("$match").Value.ToBsonDocument()
```

4.Remove element by name:

```
document.GetElement("$match").Value.ToBsonDocument().Remove(‌​"ComName")
```